# Expo AV - RecordingStatus durationMillis=0 on iOS device

Tags: expo, expo-av

This problem occurs only on the iOS device. On iOS simulator or Android device and simulator it works fine.

I am creating a recording, passing it a callback.

```
await Audio.Recording.createAsync(
        {...Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY},
        statusUpdateCallback,
      );
```

The callback receives an Audio.RecordingStatus object which should display some real time information about the recording.

```
  const statusUpdateCallback = async (status: Audio.RecordingStatus) => {
    console.log(status);
  };
```

```
 LOG  {"canRecord": true, "durationMillis": 0, "isRecording": false, "mediaServicesDidReset": false, "metering": -120}
 LOG  {"canRecord": true, "durationMillis": 0, "isRecording": false, "mediaServicesDidReset": false, "metering": -120}
 LOG  {"canRecord": true, "durationMillis": 0, "isRecording": true, "mediaServicesDidReset": false, "metering": -28.657485961914062}
 LOG  {"canRecord": true, "durationMillis": 0, "isRecording": true, "mediaServicesDidReset": false, "metering": -24.778385162353516}
```

As you can see `durationMillis` is zero on the device but it works on the simulator. What's more, it used to work on the device also, but at some point it stopped.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this, could anybody give me some pointers please?

I tried installing/uninstalling the app, using both Expo Go and a Test Flight build.

Answer (score 1):

Strange thing, it sorted itself after I restarted the iPhone.

Comment: same issue, works after restart my iPhone. It's weird, take few hours to debug :(